# Android Custom number picker issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-number-picker

I am building a library with a `NumberPicker` and two buttons which controls the Up and Down of the number.  I set the min and max to the `NumberPicker` with setMin, setMax, setValue and after that I set an ordered array in the setDisplayValues method.

I've built an example with the component isolated, and its working fine.

But when I try to use my component inside my app, the component doesn't work as expected. When the component is showed, the value limit is not the correct value. When I refresh the value, moving the picker, it sets to the proper value, and everything works fine. But the first time is not working as expected.

I tried to put the `NumberPicker`isolated in the app, an the result is the same. Any idea?

In the image where you see 14 down...there is suppose to be nothing. In the other 14 is suppose to be a 1. The max value for the picker is 14.

[image: NumberPicker issue]

Comment: Can you share the adapter of setting number to Numbers view

Comment: this is not an adapter...is the native custom picker with some themes